# Need to use rvest to scrap dynamic content

Tags: r, web-scraping, dynamic, rvest, rselenium

I have to scrap data from a auctions website called Unicorn Auctions.

[image]

When I try to do it using rvest everything that I can get is the auction title and URL, but I also need it's start and end dates. When I try to find it's CSS class all that I find is the following lines of code:

[image]

I was abre to scrape it using RSelenium as I found here in Stack Overflow. But my boss wants it to be made just with rvest. He says that it's possible, but I can't find any helpful youtube video or article.

I dont want anyone to just give me the solution, I just need some help!

Answer (score 0):

Start by searching some of those values from the page source and/or from network responses in brwoser's dev tools, "2023" for example will lead you to the correct location.

Page view variables are embedded in one of the `<script>...</script>` elements as

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    viewVars = {"escaper":{},...,"auctions": {"result_page":[{...,"time_start": "2023-11-06T01:00:00Z",...};
</script>
```

That Javascript expression is just a single assignment and when removing few bits from the start (`viewVars = {`) and from the end (`;`), the resulting string can be parsed as JSON:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

upcominng <- 
  read_html("https://bid.unicornauctions.com/") |>
  html_element(xpath = "//script[contains(text(),'viewVars =')]") |>
  html_text() |>
   # remove few bits from javascript to to make parseble as JSON
  str_remove("^\\s+viewVars =") |>
  str_remove(";\\s+$") |>
  jsonlite::fromJSON() |>
   # extract results_page from the list
  purrr::pluck("upcomingAuctions", "result_page") |>
  as_tibble()

select(upcominng, title, contains("time")) |> glimpse()
#> Rows: 4
#> Columns: 9
#> $ title                    <chr> "November 'No Reserves' Unicorn Auction 2023"…
#> $ time_start               <chr> "2023-11-06T01:00:00Z", "2023-11-13T01:00:00Z…
#> $ time_start_live_auction  <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA
#> $ time_start_proxy_bidding <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA
#> $ timezone                 <chr> "America/Chicago", "America/Chicago", "Americ…
#> $ effective_end_time       <chr> "2023-11-13T00:00:00Z", "2023-11-20T00:00:00Z…
#> $ extended_end_time        <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA
#> $ realtime_server_url      <lgl> NA, NA, NA, NA
#> $ is_times_the_money       <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>